# Unexpected costs in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bucket, google-cloud-storage

I suspect that there are unexpected costs associated with my usage of Google Cloud Storage (GCS). Here are the steps that I took which I believe may have caused the issue:

1. I wrote approximately 4 terabytes of files to the "gs://BUCKET_NAME/FOLDER_NAME1/X/YYY.asc" path in my GCS bucket. The bucket is located in the europe-west1 region and contains objects stored in the Standard storage class. (blob_new.upload_from_filename(path))
2. I ran the gsutil mv command to move approximately 4 terabytes of
   data from the `gs://BUCKET_NAME/FOLDER_NAME1*/**/`  directory to the
   root directory `gs://BUCKET_NAME/` within the same GCS bucket
   command :

> gsutil mv "gs://BUCKET_NAME/FOLDER_NAME1*/**/*.asc"
> "gs://BUCKET_NAME/"

I suspect that this step may have caused
the issue, as the dates in the Google billing graph coincide with
when I ran the gsutil mv command.

3. I downloaded the same 4 terabytes of files from the bucket to a Dataiku server. (blob.download_to_filename(path))

After reviewing my billing account, I noticed unexpected charges for network egress and operations. The reason for the unexpected charges was due to downloading data to "Worldwide Destinations (excluding Asia & Australia)". I am unsure why the data was downloaded to these destinations and would appreciate any assistance in understanding the root cause of this issue.

Comment: Where is deployed Dataiku? On GCP? on the same region as your bucket? Is it a multiregion bucket or a single region one?

Comment: dataiku is deployed on Scaleway (Paris), and the bucket on gcs is a single region one

Comment: As long as you put the data out of the same region of Google Cloud, you pay egress. Here, it's not inter-region of Google Cloud, it's worldwide, you go somewhere, obviously on Scaleway. And yes, this egress for 4Tb is not null! (about $45)

Comment: Yes, I agree. but I also have other charges when I use the "mv" command within the same bucket. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: AFAIK, "mv" shouldn't incur a lot of charges. Indeed, MV (i.e. move) doesn't not exist natively in Cloud Storage. The process start by copying the file to the new location, and then delete the original object. You can have temporarily up to 8Tb in Cloud Storage and then go back to 4Tb. Except if you activated the versioning on Cloud Storage. Additional charges can also occur if you have pick a specific class (nearline, coldline or archive). Do you have a sku for that "move"? What's the cost you observed?

Comment: I am using standard storage and versioning is not activated. The SKU is "Download Worldwide Destinations (excluding Asia & Australia)" and the cost was approximately 2000 euros. I assume there may be network fees involved since the total data size is 4TB, consisting of 533,621 files of approximately 6MB each.

Comment: you simply downloaded the files several times. No relation with the `mv` it's only egress cost. Did  you consider deploying Dataiku on Google Cloud?